# Inconsistent behavior of `dataframe.groupby(allcolumns).agg(len)`

Tags: pandas

For demonstration purposes, first, I define a couple of simple dataframes, `df0` and `df1`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import collections as co
>>> data = [['a',  1],
...         ['b',  2],
...         ['a',  3],
...         ['b',  1],
...         ['a',  2],
...         ['a',  3],
...         ['b',  1]]
>>> colnames = tuple('XY')
>>> df0 = pd.DataFrame(co.OrderedDict([(colnames[i],
...                                     [row[i] for row in data])
...                                    for i in range(len(colnames))]))
>>> df0
   X  Y
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  a  3
3  b  1
4  a  2
5  a  3
6  b  1
>>>
>>> df1 = df0.ix[:, [0]]
>>> df1
   X
0  a
1  b
2  a
3  b
4  a
5  a
6  b
```

Now, here's the result of grouping on *all* the columns of `df0` and aggregating with `len` as aggregator function:

```
>>> df0.groupby(['X', 'Y']).agg(len)
X  Y
a  1    1
   2    1
   3    2
b  1    2
   2    1
dtype: int64
```

Based on this result, I expected that the analogous operation for `df1`, namely `df1.groupby(['X']).agg(len)`, would give this:

```
X
a  4
b  3
dtype: int64
```

But that's not what happens:

```
>>> df1.groupby(['X']).agg(len)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [a, b]
```

My questions are:

1. Is this difference in behavior something that I could have expected on the basis of some pandas documentation, or is it a bug in pandas?  (If the former is the case, please point me to the relevant documentation.)
2. What's the simplest way to get the output I expected (as shown above) from `df1.groupby(['X']).agg(len)`?

Comment: The simplest way to get what you're looking for in #2 may be a pivot table. Reset the index, then use df1.pivot_table(index='X', values='index', aggfunc=len)

Answer (score 2):

See the note at the bottom of the aggrgation section: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation. Pandas 'eats' the aggregator column, so you are left with nothing to aggregate.

You essentially have a Series at this point. So you could do this:

```
In [63]: s = df1['X']

In [64]: s.groupby(s).agg(len)
Out[64]: 
X
a    4
b    3
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

Pandas doesn't do this automatically because its very hard to figure out that is what you want and makes the logic even more complicated. I suppose you could call it a bug (in that it should raise), but it is technically valid.